# DAPR middleware: OPA. Broken configuration

Tags: middleware, opa, dapr

I have set up DAPR to run a sidecar on my application that's absolutely fine. i am now trying to get OPA injected as middleware in the DAPR call. this should be simple... Set up the application annotation to config, the pipeline configuration, and the component:

Application annotation:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    metadata:
      ...
      annotations:
        dapr.io/enabled: "true"
        dapr.io/app-id: "appname"
        dapr.io/app-port: "1003"
        dapr.io/config: "opa-pipeline"
```

Pipeline configuration:

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Configuration
metadata:
  name: opa-pipeline
  namespace: default
spec:
  httpPipeline:
    handlers:
    - name: opa-component
      type: middleware.http.opa
```

Component:

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: opa-component
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: middleware.http.opa
  version: v1
  metadata:
    - name: defaultStatus
      value: 403
    - name: rego
      value: |
        package http

        default allow = true

        # Allow may also be an object and include other properties

        # For example, if you wanted to redirect on a policy failure, you could set the status code to 301 and set the location header on the response:
        allow = {
            "status_code": 301,
            "additional_headers": {
                "location": "https://my.site/authorize"
            }
        } {
            not jwt.payload["my-claim"]
        }

        # You can also allow the request and add additional headers to it:
        allow = {
            "allow": true,
            "additional_headers": {
                "x-my-claim": my_claim
            }
        } {
            my_claim := jwt.payload["my-claim"]
        }
        jwt = { "payload": payload } {
            auth_header := input.request.headers["authorization"]
            [_, jwt] := split(auth_header, " ")
            [_, payload, _] := io.jwt.decode(jwt)
        }
```

Can anyone tell me why I have an error with this?

Error:

```
time="2021-08-19T15:32:20.3742084Z" level=info msg="enabled middleware.http.opa/ http middleware" app_id=gql instance=gql-deployment-dcccd9fcf-d7wjb scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.3.0
time="2021-08-19T15:32:20.3742963Z" level=info msg="enabled gRPC tracing middleware" app_id=gql instance=gql-deployment-dcccd9fcf-d7wjb scope=dapr.runtime.grpc.api type=log ver=1.3.0
time="2021-08-19T15:32:20.3744374Z" level=info msg="enabled gRPC metrics middleware" app_id=gql instance=gql-deployment-dcccd9fcf-d7wjb scope=dapr.runtime.grpc.api type=log ver=1.3.0
time="2021-08-19T15:32:20.3745582Z" level=info msg="API gRPC server is running on port 50001" app_id=gql instance=gql-deployment-dcccd9fcf-d7wjb scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.3.0
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x16ceb7a]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/dapr/dapr/pkg/middleware/http.Pipeline.Apply(0xc000499118, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc000b084c0, 0x1)
    /home/runner/work/dapr/dapr/pkg/middleware/http/http_pipeline.go:27 +0x3a
github.com/dapr/dapr/pkg/http.(*server).useComponents(...)
    /home/runner/work/dapr/dapr/pkg/http/server.go:110
github.com/dapr/dapr/pkg/http.(*server).StartNonBlocking(0xc0005cc180)
    /home/runner/work/dapr/dapr/pkg/http/server.go:64 +0x67
github.com/dapr/dapr/pkg/runtime.(*DaprRuntime).startHTTPServer(0xc000a78a00, 0xdac, 0x1e61, 0x3faf1b0, 0x1, 0xc000499118, 0x1, 0x1)
    /home/runner/work/dapr/dapr/pkg/runtime/runtime.go:786 +0x512
github.com/dapr/dapr/pkg/runtime.(*DaprRuntime).initRuntime(0xc000a78a00, 0xc000312bb0, 0xa, 0xc0005bb180)
    /home/runner/work/dapr/dapr/pkg/runtime/runtime.go:345 +0x63b
github.com/dapr/dapr/pkg/runtime.(*DaprRuntime).Run(0xc000a78a00, 0xc000abff40, 0x7, 0x7, 0x66, 0xc00009e000)
    /home/runner/work/dapr/dapr/pkg/runtime/runtime.go:221 +0x25e
main.main()
    /home/runner/work/dapr/dapr/cmd/daprd/main.go:151 +0x1126
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in parsing value of the defaultStatus: https://github.com/dapr/dapr/issues/3216. It was fixed in v1.5.